# What C# data store should I use?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a test framework and not sure what is best to use to store test case names and data that will be provided in XML file. For example, I want to test printer functionality so it has constructor, open printer connection, send data to printer, close printer connection.   So the XML would be:

```
<Printer>
  <TestCaseName>"Printer_Construct"</TestCaseName>
    <Data1>"Printer1"</Data1>

  <TestCaseName>"Printer_OpenConnection"</TestCaseName>
    <Data1>"Printer1"</Data1>

  <TestCaseName>"Printer_PrintString"</TestCaseName>
    <Data1>"Printer1"</Data1>
    <Data2>"Printing my string"</Data2>

  <TestCaseName>"Printer_CloseConnection"</TestCaseName>
    <Data1>"Printer1"</Data1>
</Printer>
```

Here is how my test framework wanted to work:

1- when test operator runs the test framework, first it will load all the case names only into listbox1.  It will not load test case data yet.

2- when test operator selects specific test case to run, it will load that test case into listbox2.  So when it loads test case into listbox2, it will display test case name and test data(data1 and data2 as shown in xml struct above).

3- So now that test case in listbox2 is ready to be tested whenever test operator clicks the Run button.

So how can I store test case data?  Should I store these data in memory?  If so, what storing data feature should I use?  If not storing these data in memory, does that means I will have to read the XML every time when accessing to test case data so is it good practice to do that?

thanks.

Comment: Your XML is probably wrong. `Data1` and `Data2` don't belong to specific test cases and are direct children of `Printer` which is probably something you didn't mean.

Comment: Any reason you've decided to create your own test framework rather than using one of the many excellent, existing test frameworks?

Comment: You're right Dan Abramov, I should contruct it better but the XML itself is valid.  I will contruct it again like the Anwser#2 provided by JirkA Hanika.

Comment: lan Mercer, honestly I haven't looked at much test framework out there.  I look at TUX, but it does not fit the requirements so I feel it better if I create my own to match what my team requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define the test cases in XML, then you might benefit from defining its structure in an XML Schema Definition file and using a [tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to generate in-memory data structures as well as the deserializer (automated reader) from that `.xsd` file.  The tool will provide you with a `C#` file that you can include in your program.  You will be surprised how easy to work with this representation can be.

However, before you start, while your XML structure may work in this very simple initial case, it does not seem very maintainable.  If the "data" nodes logically belong to the "test case" node that precedes them, it should be so even in the XML structure, like this:

```
<Printer>
    <TestCaseName Name="Printer_Construct">
        <Data1>"Printer1"</Data1>
    </TestCaseName>

    <TestCaseName Name="Printer_PrintString">
        <Data1>"Printer1"</Data1>
        <Data2>"Printing my string"</Data2>
    </TestCaseName>
</Printer>
```

Comment: I would go further to suggest that he should make Data an Xml Array, and just have:
 <DataList> <Data>"Printer1"</Data><Data>"Printing my string"</Data></DataList>

Comment: Great, I will try your suggestion using XML Schema Definition tool and thanks for fixing my XML structure.

Answer (score 1):

Where you store this sort of information is largely dependant on what your interface is.

For a windows application (console or winforms), you can just store it in memory the first time it is needed and continue to look it up.

If, on the other hand, it is a web interface, I would highly recommend the built in .net web caching. It is extremely efficient and has powerful options for cache expiry like being able to have the file reload any time you change the file, and persist otherwise.

Comment: Yep, my test framework is winforms.  Do you know what data struct I should use?  Right now I'm using ArrayList, and it seems to work OK for storing test case name, but when stores test case data along with test case name, little bit tricky.

Comment: Ok I am going with Dictionary instead of ArrayList.

Comment: Yeap ArrayLists are a bit antiquated. Generic lists (List<>, Dictionary<>) are much better.